# Discrete Bivariate Distributions, find constant $c$

Tags: probability, statistics

I am given $f(x,y) = c(x + y)$, and I have to find constant $c$ such that $f(x,y)$ satisfies the conditions of being a joint pmf for two discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$.

$x = 1$, 2, 3, and $y = 1,\ \dots,\ x$.

I do not understand what $y$ equals. My understanding of the double sum is that I add $(1+1) + (1 + 2) + (1 + 3)$ with $(2 + 1)$, $(2 + 2)$, $(2 + 3)$, etc. I come up with a total of $36$, making $c = 1/36$. Some how the answer is $24$, making $c = 1/24$, so my interpretation of what $y = 1,\ ...,\ x$ means is wrong. Could someone give me a hand, please?

Answer (score 3):

$y$ varies from $1$ to the value of $x$, which is random. If $x = 1$ then $y$ can only equal $1$, if $x = 2$ then $y$ ranges from $1$ to $2$, etc. You need to sum over $y$ first, then over $x$. I'm not sure how you arrived at a total of $36$ but you need to calculate

$$\sum_{x=1}^{3}\sum_{y=1}^{x}c(x+y)$$

Evaluate the inside summation first: $$\sum_{y=1}^{x}c(x+y) = c\sum_{y=1}^{x}x+c\sum_{y=1}^{x}y$$

Note that $$\sum_{y=1}^{x}x = x \times x = x^2$$

Also, it is known that $$\sum_{y=1}^{x}y = \frac{x(x+1)}{2}$$

(you can look it up in a standard summation table). Overall $$\sum_{y=1}^{x}c(x+y) = c\left(x^2 + \frac{x(x+1)}{2}\right)$$ Now sum this over $x$:

$$\sum_{x=1}^{3}c\left(x^2 + \frac{x(x+1)}{2}\right) =24c$$

Since everything must sum to $1$ you require $c = 1/24$.